# I can not unsubscribe web socket in Firefox

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firefox, atmosphere

I'm using atmosphere and angularJS for creating the client application.
I want to unsubscribe ws when user click Back button in browser or change location page.
My code was working normally in Chrome 38, Safari but not working in Firefox 33.
I'm using angular-atmosphere-service to handle ws.

Link: [github.com > spyboost > angular-atmosphere-service.js](https://github.com/spyboost/angular-atmosphere/blob/master/service/angular-atmosphere-service.js)

```
var unbindHandler = $scope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function (event, next, current) {
  var path = $location.path();
  event.preventDefault();

  showPopupAlert('confirm', $('#popup_alert'),
    function () {
      try {
        atmosphereService.unsubscribe(request);
      } catch(e) {
        $log.debug(e);
      }
      $scope.$apply(function () {
        unbindHandler();
        $location.url(path).replace();
      });
    }, function () {
    }, errorMes('client.changepage.on.pumping'));
});


function showPopupAlert(type, obj, confirmFunction, rejectFunction, message) {
  if (type != 'confirm') {
    obj.find('#btn-cancel').hide();
  } else {
    obj.find('#btn-cancel').show();
  }

  obj.find('#question').html(message);
  obj.modal('show');

  obj.find('#btn-ok').unbind().bind('click', function () {
    obj.modal('hide');
    if (confirmFunction !== 0) {
      confirmFunction();
    }
  });

  obj.find('#btn-cancel').unbind().bind('click', function () {
    obj.modal('hide');
    if (rejectFunction !== 0) {
      rejectFunction();
    }
  });
}
```

Open console log in Firefox, I got an object

columnNumber

```
0
```

data

```
null
```

filename

```
"http://192.168.1.102/ser.../libs/atmosphere-min.js"
```

inner

```
null
```

lineNumber

```
635
```

message

```
""
```

name

```
""
```

result

```
2153644038
```

stack

```
"J@http://192.168.1.102/s...query/jquery.js:3:4749\n"
```

**proto**

```
Object { toString=toString(), message=undefined, name=undefined}
```

Comment: I include showPopupAlert function

Comment: What does `not working` exactly mean? Any errors in console? Besides, is it a requirement to support such rather old browsers?

Comment: I have updated the console log. I think atmosphere services are not supported in Firefox. Is not FF38 certainly too old?

Comment: There seems to be a trouble with [unsubscribing in this project](https://github.com/spyboost/angular-atmosphere/issues/1) and author seems to be pretty unresponsive. Besides last commit into the repo was 2 years ago. I would suppose the project is dead